# Not deploy container on master node in Docker Swarm

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I am working on a project which uses Raspberry Pis as worker nodes and my laptop as the master node. I hope to control the deployment of my containers from my laptop, but I hope the containers run on the worker nodes only(which means no container on the master node). How can I do it with Docker Swarm?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am going to presume you are using a stack.yml file to describe your deployment using desired-state, but `docker service create` does have flags for this too.

There are a number of values that docker defines that can be tested under a placement-constraints node:

```yaml
version: "3.9"

service:
  worker:
    image: nginx
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints:
        - node.role==worker
```

Comment: Exactly what I am looking for. Thank you.